# Use HTML form as GUI for powershell

Tags: html, events, powershell

I have a powershell script that I would like to run using an html form.  All I have is a few form fields and a button.  When I run my powershell script, it opens a new ie window, and then navigates to the correct page with the form.  How do I gather the information that gets filled out in the form after the user clicks the button?

**EDIT:**

Here is some code I'm trying to get working:

```
function onClick($server)
{
    $server.value="here"
}

$ie = new-object -com "Internetexplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("bulk_upload.html")
$ie.visible = $true

$doc = $ie.document
$btn = $doc.getElementById("submit")
$server = $doc.getElementById("server")

$btn.add_onclick({onClick $server})
```

I run this code and nothing happens after I click the button

**UPDATE**

I tried running this code:

```
$ie = new-object -com "Internetexplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("bulk_upload.html")
$ie.visible = $true

$doc = $ie.document
$btn = $doc.getElementById("submit")

$eventId = Register-ObjectEvent $btn HTMLButtonElementEvents_Event_onclick -Action {write-host 'hi'}
```

And I get this error:

*Cannot register for event.  Events that require a return value are not supported*

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to accomplish the same thing and ran across your post. I see it's been about 8 months, but if you're still looking here's what I found. I was not able to get "onclick" to work. So I used a hidden input field, and defined an action for the button to update the value of that field. In powershell I getElementbyId for the hidden field, and use that to recognize the user has completed the input.

```
$html = @"
<html>
<body>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname">
<br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="finished" value="0">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Continue" onclick="finished.value=1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
"@

$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate2("about:blank")
$ie.AddressBar  = $false
$ie.MenuBar     = $false
$ie.StatusBar   = $false

$ie.document.body.innerHTML = $html
$ie.Visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document

while ($doc.getElementByID("finished").value -ne 1) {
    start-sleep -m 500
}

$ie.Visible = $false
"You answered:"
$doc.getElementByID("firstname").value
$doc.getElementByID("lastname").value
$ie.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The following article on Web UI automation with PowerShell may help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx

Comment: I saw that one, but it's not what I am looking for.  That automates a web form.  I don't want to automate it, I want to grab what the user inputs into the form

Comment: You can get the input, that's not the problem. What is more challenging is how to determine "when to do it". There are some events on the com object (InternetExplorer.Automation) which might help.

Comment: I've been trying to use those events with no luck.  I also noticed that there is a method called add_onclick.  I tried adding that to my button, and nothing happens.  I changed my question to show this

Answer (score 1):

I know you specified an HTML form but you might be better off writing a WinForms GUI for this instead.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_GUIs_in_Windows_PowerShell_1.0_with_WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Because you are already able to open a new ie window from your powershell script and navigate to the correct page, I'm assuming that you are using [InternetExplorer Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28VS.85%29.aspx). That's why I'm thinking @ravikanth link is good for you. From there (and from many other posts on the internet) you can see how to grab value fields using [`$ie.Document.getElementById("fieldid").value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28VS.85%29.aspx), do you?

Another option is [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) which is the proper way to GET/POST web page data. You have a nice example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx#ctl00_WikiContent_ctl00_Header).

Otherwise, I think you should be more clear about what you want to do and provide some code sample of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering if this actually works well:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-add-a-graphical-user-interface-to-a-powershell-script-by-using-html-applications.aspx

It's based around running a PowerShell process from VBScript and then using the clipboard to transfer the output back to the HTA.

Sounds like a half decent hack, I've not tried it for myself yet though.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I add javascript by using the execScript("SCRIPT HERE","Type Of Script") of the parent window

```
$html = @"
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
                First name: <input type="text" id="firstname">
            <br>
                Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="finished" value="Submit" onclick=''>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
"@

$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("about:blank")
$ie.document.body.innerHTML = $html
$doc = $ie.Document
$doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.getElementById('finished').onclick = function(){document.getElementById('finished').value = 'Submitted';};","javascript")
$ie.Visible = $true

while ($doc.getElementByID("finished").value -ne "Submitted") {
    start-sleep -m 500
    $firstName = $doc.getElementByID("firstname").value
    $lastName = $doc.getElementByID("lastname").value
}

$ie.Visible = $false
"You answered:"
$doc.getElementByID("firstname").value
$doc.getElementByID("lastname").value
$ie.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Clayton It works fine for on other windows 10 OS System but gives an error on Windows 10 Azure VM

Error-
The property 'innerHTML' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:24 char:1

- $ie.document.body.innerHTML = $html