# innerHTML error when using HTML form as GUI powershell

Tags: javascript, html, azure, powershell, innerhtml

[Use HTML form as GUI for powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981905/use-html-form-as-gui-for-powershell/9132097#9132097)

Below code works fine, however, i get an error when using it on Azure VM

=============Error=============

```
Error- 
The property 'innerHTML' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the 
property exists and can be set.
At line:24 char:1
+ $ie.document.body.innerHTML = $html
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
***
```

=================Code=================

```
$html = @"
<HTML>
<body>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname">
<br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="finished" value="0">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Continue"onclick="finished.value=1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
"@

$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate2("about:blank")
$ie.AddressBar  = $false
$ie.MenuBar     = $false
$ie.StatusBar   = $false
   
$ie.document.body.innerHTML = $html
$ie.Visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document
   
while ($doc.getElementByID("finished").value -ne 1) {
    start-sleep -m 500
}
   
$ie.Visible = $false
"You answered:"
$doc.getElementByID("firstname").value
$doc.getElementByID("lastname").value
$ie.quit()
```

Comment: What's the host OS in the VM?  Normally IE displays a prompt you have to interact with before you can do anything in Internet Explorer.  Also, super creative use of an IE object, never seen anyone doing this before.

Comment: @foxDeploy windows 10

Comment: Launch it on the new VM and see what happens.  Could be that IE will not render until you accept the IE Security message.  If so, then there's a registry key to set to get rid of that message.

Comment: @Foxdeploy the use of an IE object is actually one of the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44337301/4910940

Comment: tried different VM same error